# Pass string from one function to the next javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, api, function

I've got a simple JavaScript client that pulls from a REST API to present some book data, however I seem unable to call the function createBookRow(bookid) and return the appropriate html string to the document ready function where it is called,

The output is currently being produced correctly as verified by the append to .row-fluid on the html page, ideas or suggestions welcome

```
function createBookRow(bookid)
{
$.get('http://mysite.co.uk/atiwd/books/course/'+bookid+'/xml', function(xml){  

$(xml).find('book').each(function(){  
var $book = $(this); 
var id = $book.attr("id"); 
        var title = $book.attr("title");  
        var isbn = $book.attr("isbn");
        var borrowedcount = $book.attr("borrowedcount");
        var  html = '<div class="span3"><img name="test" src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/'+isbn+'-L.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt=""></p>' ; 
         html += '<p> ' + title + '</p>' ;  
         html += '<p> ' + isbn + '</p>' ;  
         html += '<p> ' + borrowedcount + '</p>' ;  
         html += '</div>';  
        $('.row-fluid').append($(html));  
    });         
}); 
}



 $(document).ready(function()  
  {  
    $.get('xml/courses.xml', function(xml){  
    $(xml).find('course').each(function(){ 

        var $course = $(this); 
        var id = $course.attr("id"); 
        var title = $course.text();  
        var html = '<div class="span12"><p>' + title + '</p><row id="'+id+'" >'+createBookRow(id)+'</row></div>' ;  
        $('.row-fluid').append($(html));   
        $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400); 
    });  
});


});
```

Comment: `createBookRow` is a asynchronous function, you can't use it like that

Comment: '+' is concatenation operator for string. But your function not returning any strings

Comment: i've created a jsFiddle but i need some data from courses.xml to complete it: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/Sd3zb/

Comment: html is just a string variable. Why are you using $(html) in append. It should be `$('.row-fluid').append(html);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
 var html = '<div class="span12"><p>' + title + '</p><row id="'+id+'" >'+createBookRow(id)+'</row></div>' ;
```

should be just

```
 var html = '<div class="span12"><p>' + title + '</p><row id="'+id+'" ></row></div>' ; 
 createBookRow(id);
```

createBookRow(id) function is making a get request to get some details, which happens asynchronously. Unless you explicitly mention it is a synchronous call(which is not advised).

I guess the functionality you need is to render some rows for course and in between you need books details displayed. In that case you need to explicitly say where your book row needs to be appended.

```
 $('.row-fluid').append($(html));
```

The above code will always append book row at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything in the code you provided. You just append some HTML to a jQuery object. Try adding a return statement

```
return html;
```